# Difference between "API" and "compileOnly" dependencies in android 3.0 gradle dependency

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, gradle-dependencies

Since android studio 3.0 when I build a project a new syntax `API` and `compileOnly` is added in gradle dependency section like below:

```
API 'dependency library'
```

We can also use `compileOnly` instead of `API` here like below:

```
compileOnly 'dependency library'
```

What is actual difference between `API` and `compileOnly` ? When we should use what for our application.Any better example regarding this?

Comment: compileOnly or providedOnly ?

Comment: Check here. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations

Comment: compileOnly edited.